# null pointer exception error when revoking EJB method

Tags: jboss, nullpointerexception, ejb, local, stateless

I am new in creating Java modules, currently I'm trying to call method which inserts data into database. I have an 1) interface TestSEI. 2) The webservice called TestWS, implements TestSEI. 3) Class TestBean which implements methods which I call from TestWS. In this class I added new method DocPay, which have to call method from another EJB Module (named PayTestmodule) from class TestDB. I added  PayTestmodule in dependency in my project. 
In Netbeans I am succesfully build and deploy EAR file on Jobss, but when I revoke method DocPay in class TestBean I get error - Null pointer exception. I spend all day to fing out possible solution, but no success. Here some snippets:
1.TestSEI

```
@WebService(name="TestWS")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style Document)
public interface TestSEI {
......
```

2.TestWS

```
@WebService
public class TestWS implements TestSEI {
@Inject 
private TestBean domain
....
domain.DocPay(Object RQU)
...
```

3.TestBean

```
@stateless
@Localbean
public class TestBean {
....
Public DocPay(Object request)
PayDB dbapi=new PayDB();
String id=dbapi.insertdata(Stringparams)
....
```

4.PayDB class(defined in another EJB module)

```
@Stateless
public class PayDB implements PayDBLocal
......
Publis String insertdata(Stringparams) throws ....
```

5.PayDBLocal

```
@Local
public interface PayDBLocal
.......
```

Please, help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please post the stack trace and the full methods in `TestWS` and `PayDB`, not one line only

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean *"when I revoke method DocPay in class TestBean"* or its in `TestWS`??

Use this in `TestWS`

```
@EJB
private TestBean domain
```